# Cloudant sync in android

Tags: java, android, database, synchronization, cloudant

I am working with cloudant for sync in remote DB, I tried calling DatastoreManager and this is where i got few errors eventhough after importing all packages. I am new to cloudant someone guide me. I have submitted my part of code below

```
File path = getApplicationContext().getDir("datastores", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
DatastoreManager manager = new DatastoreManager(path.getAbsolutePath());
URI uri = new URI("https://username:password@username.cloudant.com/my_database"); 
Datastore ds  = manager.openDatastore("my_datastore"); // Create a replicator that replicates changes from the remote // database to the local datastore. 
PullReplication pull = new PullReplication(); 
pull.source = uri; 
pull.target = ds; 
Replicator replicator = ReplicatorFactory.oneway(pull);
```

Following is my error code

*java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/eventbus/EventBus;*

Someone guide me in right direction. Thank you

Comment: Are you running this with progaurd / minify options turned on in your gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the guava.jar file, it is needed for this import
        `import com.google.common.eventbus.Subscribe;`
you can download it from here [Guava.jar](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

good luck!

Comment: I added guava.jar file